# Is Azure AD (only) enough for simple identity requirements

Tags: active-directory, azure

I'm looking at helping out a small business, who currently operates four very small branch offices (ranging from 4 - 10 windows PCs). Currently, shared accounts are used on these machines - obviously this is a pain, not to mention the security aspect.

Access to information once logged into each machine is restricted via practice management software; the accounts to which are thankfully managed centrally.

Ideally I'd like to create a windows login for each user. Is it possible to do this with Azure AD, without a local domain controller? If it is, where does the Azure AD functionality end? Would it be possible to say, deploy a policy to map a shared drive upon login?

Due to the small budget of the business, it would be unfeasible to deploy a domain controller at different sites, for a little as four PCs.

Comment: take a look at azure domain joined devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to create a windows login for each user. Is it possible to do
> this with Azure AD, without a local domain controller?

Yes. You can join the computers to Azure AD and each user can log in with their Azure AD username and password.

> Would it be possible to say, deploy a policy to map a shared drive
> upon login?

If you have Intune licenses you can create a drive mappings configuration profile. There's a handy tool for doing this at the URL below.

https://intunedrivemapping.azurewebsites.net/